# How can I set a property dynamically on an interceptor in spring integration

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-integration, interceptor

We have a webservice outbound gateway with an interceptor that does some pre and post processing, we need to set dynamically a property of the interceptor, something very similar to this [how to pass values through http headers dynamically using spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434487/how-to-pass-values-through-http-headers-dynamically-using-spring-integration) situation and we tried to implement the suggested solution, but we get an exception at runtime.

Here the relevant code:

**the Interceptor relevant code**

```
public class WebServiceClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
    private final ThreadLocal<HashMap<String, String>> customHeaders = new ThreadLocal<HashMap<String, String>>();
  .....
    public GenericMessage setCustomHeaders(GenericMessage message, String property, String value) {
        log.info("Adding header");
        if (customHeaders.get() == null) {
            log.info("map was null");
            customHeaders.set(new HashMap<String, String>());
        }
        log.info("set " + property + ": " + value);
        customHeaders.get().put(property, value);
        return message;
    }
```

**the context definition**

```
<int:chain id="getOperatorTynTecCallChain"
    input-channel="inspector.getoperator.tyntec.enricher.input.channel"
    output-channel="inspector.getoperator.results.enricher.output.channel">
    <int:service-activator expression="@webServiceClientInterceptor.setCustomHeaders(#root, 'mcc' , headers.mcc.getFirst())" />
    <int:transformer method="transformRequest" ref="tynTecInspectorPartnerImpl" />
    <int-ws:header-enricher id="getOperatorTynTecHeaderEnricher">
        <int-ws:soap-action value="urn:SyncSuperQueryService" />
    </int-ws:header-enricher>
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="getOperatorTynTecOutboundHttpGateway"
        marshaller="xmlBeansMarshaller" unmarshaller="xmlBeansTynTecUnmarshaller"
        requires-reply="true" message-sender="httpComponentsMessageSender"
        uri="${scoretools.inspector.tyntec.url}"> 
        <interceptor="webServiceClientInterceptor">
    </int-ws:outbound-gateway>

    <int:service-activator expression="@tynTecInspectorPartnerImpl.transformResponse(payload, headers.msisdn, headers.mcc)" />
</int:chain>

<bean id="webServiceClientInterceptor" name="webServiceClientInterceptor"
    class="com.cliqdigital.inspector.util.WebServiceClientInterceptor" />
```

**the exception**

```
16:23:56,338 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor] (default task-1) SpEL Expression evaluation failed with EvaluationException.: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 29): Method call: Method setCustomHeaders() cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52 type
```

Looks like when the interceptor is wrapped in the proxy the method setCustoHeaders gets lost, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Why is the interceptor being proxied?

In any case, you can change the interceptor to implement an interface that has `setCustomHeaders` on it (as well as `ClientInterceptor`).

The proxy will expose all methods from interfaces.

```
public class WebServiceClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor, CustomHeaderSetter {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I love you, I was actually hoping you could pick this question up, and as usual you did quickly and effectively.
We will try what you suggest and tell you about the outcome, btw I have no idea why the interceptor is being proxied, but I think we will spend less time finding a workaround (i.e. using the Interface approach) than investigate why it is proxied and make it not proxied.
Thanks, Andrea